# Destroy Direct2D bitmap?

Tags: bitmap, direct2d, c++builder-xe7

I'm using C++ Builder XE7. Whenever a form resizes I need to rebuild a D2D bitmap, which I create with CreateBitmap(). As this will quickly eat up all video memory, I want to destroy the previous bitmap before creating a new one. Oddly enough I cannot find any information how to destroy this _di_ID2D1Bitmap. I tried the Release() method but that just gives me an AV in line 291 of systobj.h.

What is the proper way to destroy a _di_ID2D1Bitmap?

Thanks.

Comment: If _di_ID2D1Bitmap is the `ID2D1Bitmap` interface, just remove all references to it (eg. `mySavedBMPRef = null`).

Comment: Thanks @PeterKostov. Is it that simple? My confusion comes from the fact I look at this like a pointer, which I now understand it isn't. I assume not nilling it but replacing it to "point" to the new bitmap works just as well?

Comment: `_di_ID2D1Bitmap` is a `DelphiInterface`. A variable of that type is a pointer. You don't have to free it manually, because there is an automatic reference counting - ie - when there are no references left, it will be freed automatically. In short, if you have a pointer `P` holding **just one** reference to your `ID2D1Bitmap`, when you pass it to the `CreateBitmap()` it will acquire a ref to the new bitmap while the old one will became with 0 references and will be freed.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Not familiar with Delphi so did not know that (nor is it documented). If you post that as answer I'll give you proper credits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_di_ID2D1Bitmap` is a [`DelphiInterface`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.DelphiInterface). An interface reference in Delphi is a pointer to pointer to an IMT. So, a variable of `_di_ID2D1Bitmap` type is a pointer.

You don't have to free it manually, because there is an automatic reference counting - ie - when there are no references left, it will be freed automatically. You may check the [`IInterface._AddRef`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_IInterface__AddRef.html) and [`IInterface._Release`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_IInterface__Release.html) methods.

In short, if you have a pointer `P` holding **just one** reference to your `ID2D1Bitmap` (ie `_di_ID2D1Bitmap`), when you pass it to the `CreateBitmap()` it will acquire a ref to the new bitmap while the old one will became with 0 references and will be freed.

Here are some useful reads:

- [Delphi reference counted interfaces](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30125)
- [Delphi interfaces on binary level](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/delphi-interfaces-on-binary-level/)